# ubuntu 18.04 guest on mac 10.14 host - keyboard unresponsive when ssh'ing into google chrome 77 but it works when chrome is opened from within guest

Tags: 18.04, ssh, virtualbox, google-chrome, vagrant

I have Ubuntu 18.04 running successfully on Mac Mojave via virtualBox and Vagrant.

When Chrome is opened via the GUI, mouse and keyboard inputs are accepted:

[I can type like a monkey on a keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVi1N.png)

But when I enter the following command on the terminal I can't use the keyboard (pressing a key causes the window to flash but there is no input. The mouse works; I can click links and select text):

```
$ defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 enable_iglx -bool true
$ ssh -X -p 2222 vagrant@localhost google-chrome-stable --disable-gpu
```

Incidentally, during troubleshooting, I used the `startx` command and now I get the following message when I vagrant ssh into the VM.

```
Last login: Fri Oct  4 21:20:54 2019 from 10.0.2.2
/usr/bin/xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /home/vagrant/.Xauthority
```

Now, when I try to ssh into google chrome I get the following alert:

```
/usr/bin/xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /home/vagrant/.Xauthority
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
(google-chrome-stable:4870): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:25:12.700: cannot open display: localhost:11.0
```

I have wasted a couple days on this and any guidance would be appreciated. Rather than copying and pasting everything under the sun, please advise what I should amend to this post.

Many thanks!

**Additional info**: I can ssh into gedit and chromium-browser from host terminal and the keyboard is functional. I destroyed my vm, started over and updated all packages; the keyboard is still unresponsive when chrome is opened from host terminal. I also sometimes get the following error:

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Comment: I had this issue, I believe its because hardware acceleration cannot be facilitated through ssh. I am also unsure if Xquartz allows hardware accel. Try to use `X2go` and install it on the VM as well.

Comment: @user321627 Many thanks; I have always used terminal and I was spending way too much time trying to get the GUI to work (mostly for cypress). I will give `X2go` a go and will report back when I do.